# ruby on rails myprofile page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, slug

I want to create a profile page for users that signing up
so let's say a user already registered, his profile link should be

```
website.com/profile/username
```

and on the 
`views/profile/index.html.erb` 
each user should see his own profile and edit it with the form_for I guess
so far I have `profiles_controller.rb`, `profile.rb` model and `resources :profiles`for my routes.rb
What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna get by username then you need to use slug. The example below is for `id` version.

Profile controller

```
def show
   @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end
```

routes:

```
get 'profile/:id' => 'profile#show'
```

for `:slug` version, url will be like this: `http://localhost:3000/profiles/**username**`

routes:

```
resources :profiles, param: :slug
```

profiles_controller

```
def show 
end

private

def set_profile
  @profile = Profile.find_by_username(params[:slug])
end
```

Or you can use gem for this https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: I think you should also write an example for the view?

Comment: @user4571629 You want me to make whole page ? This answer was for your question.

Comment: @user4571629 Also, if would like to edit options like in twitter, then you can get edit form by ajaxing.

Comment: Ok thanks, so basically i do also param: :permalink , I choose the name, right ?